# How to find the date of an object in Java.

Tags: java, oop

Suppose I have a class names "Test" and I create an instance of that class, Can I know the creation date of that instance?

Comment: You can't, unless you already have a (instance) variable, in your class `Test`, that does the same!

Comment: Why do you care *when* the object was created?

Comment: @Raedwald: I care because I have to check the creation time of an instance as I am using a singleton design pattern.

Comment: No, still makes no sense. Why do you care when your singleton was created?

Comment: @Raedwald Sounds like the purpose is testing. By checking the date-time of instantiation you can verify that you did create one and only one instance versus having replaced an instance.

Comment: Note that objects created at different times will probably have different identity-hash values, even if their (overridden) `Thing.equals()` evaluates as true.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll have to take care of that yourself, by having a Date instance member in your `Test` class and initializing it in your constructor (or in its declaration) with the current Date.

```
public class Test {

    Date date = new Date ();

    public Date getCreationDate ()
    {
        return date;
    }
}
```

Comment: that is alright but I need to implement a singleton design pattern where each instance is linked with its creation date so that we may know when that particular instance was created. 

Any comments on how to implement it would be helpful.

Comment: @MayankSharma It sounds like you are asking for a mapping of your instances to their creation dates. You can easily achieve it with a Map, but what's the point? Given any instance, you can get its creation date by calling the `getCreationDate()` method.

Comment: @MayankSharma Doesn't singleton mean that there is only one instance?

Answer (score 5):

No, objects do not have implicit timestamps.  If you need to know, then add an instance variable to your class.

```
public class Test {
    private final Date creationDate = new Date();

    public Date getCreationDate() {
        return creationDate; // or a copy of creation date, to be safe
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't compile, you fogot to specify type of `creationDate`.

Comment: that is alright but I need to implement a singleton design pattern where each instance is linked with its creation date so that we may know when that particular instance was created. Any comments on how to implement it would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

## Avoid `java.util.Date`

The other two answers are correct, except that the java.util.Date class has been outmoded by the new [java.time package](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) ([Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)) in Java 8. The old java.util.Date/.Calendar classes are notoriously troublesome, confusing, and flawed. Avoid them.

## java.time

Get the current moment in java.time.

```
ZonedDateTime instantiated = ZonedDateTime.now();
```

## UTC

Generally better to get in the habit of doing your back-end work (business logic, database, storage) all in UTC time zone. The code above relies implicitly on the JVM’s current default time zone.

To get the current moment in UTC in java.time.

```
ZonedDateTime instantiated = ZonedDateTime.now( ZoneOffset.UTC );
```